# DialogResult or how to make a custom dialog

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I want to have a dialog with only 3 buttons. I am coding in C# as well and there I can assign a DialogResult (OK, CANCEL, ABORT and many more)

What I want to ask: Is there a way to do this? I guess code from my side is not helpful.
I guess the pressed button is not difficult, but to wait till the frame has been closed.
I will write a pseudo-code what I want to achieve anyway. I am looking forward to hear your tips.

```
public int showDialog() {
    pack(); 
    setVisible(true);
    waitForFirstClick()
    return pressedButton == a? 0 : pressedbutton == b ? 1 : 2;
}
```

What I am looking is the equivilent to C# showDialog() [MSDN showDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[image: Screenshot]

When I click on one button I want to close it and I want to customize it like hell if I want (you know, it's not about the 3 buttons, but also gaining knowledge.... I want to do such things I do in C# for years in java as well)

Comment: Use JOptionPane with custom buttons. Example here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: Hi, And what if I would like to have four buttons? I will update the description how it should look like (picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of dialog/buttons is not supported by JOptionPane, but you can create a custom dialog to implement your behaviour. Use undecorated JDialog, GridLayout (1 row and 3 columns) and 3 or 4 buttons without border.